# Best practice plugin in PhpStorm

Tags: php, plugins, phpstorm

As a team member, responsible for teaching junior developers, I would like to have some possibility to warn juniors of bad practices in IDE. I have forced them to use many static analysis plugins, but I can't find any code-specific best practice plugin. For example limitation of usage of models in views, creating SQL queries in controller etc.

Is there any plugin, or any way to lock usage of certain namespaces, methods, classes in certain files ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such plugin but you can use 3rd-party tools like PHP Code Sniffer and PHP Mess Detector which can be integrated with PhpStorm.